# How do you debug a Windows Universal App built with command line?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, uwp

This is easy for a Win32 app, you just build it with cl.exe and include debugging information, then you can open the .exe in Visual Studio and step through the code. What is the equivalent for a Univeral Windows Platform (UWP) app that is distributed using an .appx?  When I try to open the .exe for it in Visual Studio 2015 (before packaging, or after unpacking the generated .appx) I just get error 0x8007006E, "The system cannot open the device or file specified".

Comment: Can you attach to the process in Visual Studio?

Comment: as WiredPrairie said why dont you just put some breakpoints by clicking at the grey that is left of the line number and the click Local Machine(or F5). When it reaches the code the breakpoint will trigger and you can see all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Once your APPX is installed, you can debug it from VS using the following steps:

1. Debug --> Other Debug Target --> Debug Installed App Package

[image]

2. Select the app you want to debug

[image]

3. Select the type of code you want to debug (managed/native)
4. Check any of the optional checkboxes (as needed)
5. Click "Start"

Thanks,

Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: How does this work with Visual Studio CMake Open Folder? Running an executable fails due to missing MSVCP140D_APP.dll and VCRUNTIME140D_APP.dll.

Comment: Make sure you have the right dependencies installed on the test machine. You can find the packages in %Program Files(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs

Comment: The test machine is my dev box, I've installed both `Microsoft.VCLibs` and `Microsoft.VCLibs.Desktop` (x64, Debug) appx packages, and it still fails to run via CMake Open Folder.

Comment: How do you try to launch the app? For a packaged app you can't just invoke the EXE, you need to either invoke the launch contract, or declare an appExecutionAlias that you can then invoke like an EXE.

Comment: I'm just hitting F5 from within Visual Studio, after opening a folder (using CMake). The projects are correctly built as 'Universal Windows` projects, it seems Visual Studio is just missing whatever "Debug / Launch" magic it uses when you open a vcxproj, instead of a CMake folder. I'll investigate launch contract and appExecutionAlias, but my feeling is that Visual Studio should "just work" (the same as opening a vcxproj). Thanks.

Comment: @MarkIngram I have connected with the VS team on this and they have confirmed that we don't have UWP support in the CMake integration yet. So for now you will have to go with the Debug menu workflow I have outlined in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that Stefan, for now I'll just generate a VS project via CMake, as that does work. Would be great for the VS team to add CMake debug support for UWP too :-).